# external Activity embedded in another Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I need to launch an external Activity (`FeedbackActivity` from the `HockeyApp` SDK.)

I want to customize the `ActionBar`, add a `Navigation Drawer` and a few more things, but I cannot modify that external `Activity`.

My idea was embedding the external `Activity` into another, so I can customize it as I want.

I've read about `ActivityGroup` but it's deprecated...

Any better idea?

Comment: `Viewpager with only 1 fragment?` is suitable **only for Fragment**, not for Activity.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry I got confused.

Comment: as for me - I think that you should not modify appearance of 3rd-party library components because this way you may violate their license agreement, and your app has chance to get banned because of that.

Comment: can't you use inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some alternatives:

1. Create your `CustomFeedbackActivity` that inherits from `FeedbackActivity` as @lelloman says to customize it (I'd go for this one)
2. Create the whole `CustomFeedbackActivity` based on [the one in the sdk](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Android/blob/03cfd6149a5e94d207e4d3c83c40ab0a78a306e7/hockeysdk/src/main/java/net/hockeyapp/android/FeedbackActivity.java) copying the code and adapting it
3. Create your own `FeedbackActivity` as you want without all the things of the one in the `HockeyApp SDK` and make the call to the [HockeyApp API](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api) by yourself

But take into consideration the license of the HockeyApp SDK in order to do that as @Vlad Matvienko said